# Why do I get "Pair cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable" error?

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class Pair<V> implements Map.Entry<V,V> {
    private V first;
    private V second;
    public Pair(){

    }
    public Pair (V first, V second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public V getKey() {
        return first;
    }

    @Override
    public V getValue() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public V setValue(V value) {
        this.second = value;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pair{" +
                "first=" + first +
                ", second=" + second +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Inside Program class I have this method:

```
public static <K,V extends Comparable> Pair<V> minmax(Map<K,V> map) {
    List<V> values = new ArrayList<V>(map.values());
    List<K> keys = new ArrayList<K>(map.keySet());
    V min = (V)min(values);
    V max = (V)max(values);
    V minKey = (V)map.get(min);
    V maxKey = (V)map.get(max);

    Pair minPair = new Pair(minKey,min);
    Pair maxPair = new Pair(maxKey,max);
    return new Pair((V)minPair,(V)maxPair);
}
```

Here the row that calls the method above:

```
    Pair minMax2 = minmax(mapGrades);
```

But on this row:

```
 return new Pair((V)minPair,(V)maxPair);
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Pair cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at Program.minmax(Program.java:35)
    at Program.main(Program.java:14)
```

Any idea why I get the error above and how to fix it?

Comment: Because you have a `Pair(Pair, Pair)` not a `Pair(V,V)`. Also, `Pair minPair` is a rawtype. You have some really dirty casting going on here, and a huge number of rawtypes. Review each and every compile warning in your code. for example, why is `min(values)` not returning a `V`?

Comment: Because `Pair` does not implement `Comparable`, so `Pair` is not a valid type for `V`.

Comment: Also - why are you assuming that `map.values()` and `map.keySet()` return things in the _same order_ - `Map` provides **no such guarantees**. It may well be the case that the `Map` provides the two things in a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minPair` and `maxPair` are of type `Pair` (well you could define them as `Pair<V>`). You can't cast them to `V`.

The type of `new Pair(minPair,maxPair)` can be `Pair<Pair<V>>`, not `Pair<V>`.

Besides, since your method should return a `Pair<V>`, it can return

```
Pair<V> minPair = new Pair<>(minKey,min);
```

or

```
Pair<V> maxPair = new Pair<>(maxKey,max);
```

but not `new Pair(minPair,maxPair)`.

Comment: There are so many problems with the code. Once the casting and rawtypes are fixed there is the problem that the `Pair` is for a pair of values but the OP is trying to return a `key -> value` pair so `new Pair<>(minKey,min)` won't work. Then there is the incorrect assumption that the key `Set` and values `Collection` are in the same order; which is also not guaranteed.